# Recycle Bin for contacts and messages

Tags: android, sms, contacts

If unfortunately delete the contact or messages, i need to restore that contact and also messages how to do this. If there is anyway to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can hope to do intercept messages or contacts to be deleted if you can see an intent passing when the official apps remove them. Then you could write a broadcast receiver that could intercept that intent and save data to a "recycle bin".

Otherwise, what you will do will be very close to backup solution : saving everything on user action to a copy of the contact/messages database and giving the opportunity to users to restore them... and there are already lots of backup apps for that.

Comment: can send me any sample coding

Comment: On SOF, it works the other around. You put your code, and ask a precise question about a problem you face, people correct it, but no one will code for you.